# How to set the active profile when creating Spring context programmatically?

Tags: spring

**tl;dr:** how to create a Spring context based on an annotation-based configuration class, while supplying active profiles?

I am trying to create a Spring context using a class with the configuration specified using annotations.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext context = 
    new org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext( com.initech.ReleaserConfig.class );
```

However when it starts up it crashes because it cannot find a required bean, but that bean does exist : albeit only under a certain profile `"myProfile"`.

How do I specify the active profile? I have a feeling I need to use one the `org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory)` constructor but I'm not sure which ones is appropriate.

---

PS- I am not using Spring Boot, but am on Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext =  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
appContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles( "myProfile" );
appContext.register( com.initech.ReleaserConfig.class );
appContext.refresh();
```

Comment: That won't work since instantiating the application context causes the exception so I can never get to the `.getEnvironment()` call.

Comment: your answer led to the solution so I completed it so that it works

Comment: @ArtB you can use `System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "myProfile");` before instantiate the context

Comment: Hi @ArtB How you solved this problem ? can you please share more information ? I am also stuck at same problem find my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422271/how-to-dynamically-switch-application-context-in-spring-security

Comment: The accepted answer solved my problem and I even editted to include the missing details I needed.

Comment: Or you can set Windows System Environment Variable as `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` = `myProfile`. (You need to restart your IDE if you run the code via IDE.)

Comment: Or you can add Environment Variable as `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` = `myProfile` from your IDE's run configuration for test.

Comment: These last two comments describe non-programmatic ways of setting the active Spring profiles. Both are fine options; however, this question asked for a programmatic way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want **classpath:resources/application-${spring.profiles.active}.yml** to be working, setting system properties before refreshing is the way to go.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
applicationContext.getEnvironment().getSystemProperties().put(AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, "dev");
applicationContext.scan("com.sample");
applicationContext.refresh();
```