# Spring Framework: Why the active profiles declared programmatically are working if the "refresh" method was not executed?

Tags: spring, spring-profiles

About `Spring Framework` 3.x and 4.x (**nothing** about `Spring Boot` ) if my memory does not fail me, I remember when the *active profiles* are declared *programmatically* then the `refresh` method must be called, it **after** of the profiles declaration, otherwise the profiles are not reflected when Spring is running its own *Application Context*.

It is reflected at:

- [How to set the active profile when creating Spring context programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40269792/3665178)

Code from the shared answer

```
final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext =  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
appContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles( "myProfile" );
appContext.register( com.initech.ReleaserConfig.class );
appContext.refresh(); <--- must be executed after of the profiles declaration
```

Now with `Spring Framework` **6** for academic purposes I tried the following:

```
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx =
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.manuel.jordan.config");
    ctx.getEnvironment().setDefaultProfiles("default", "dev");
    ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("jdbc", "mysql");
```

As you can see the `refresh` method was **not** executed, it to demonstrate that the *active profiles* were ignored. **But** it works, through the following code it was confirmed

```
for(String activeProfile : ctx.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()) {
    System.out.println(" " + activeProfile);
}
```

and even more, the constructor code with the `String` parameter of the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` is:

```
/**
 * Create a new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, scanning for components
 * in the given packages, registering bean definitions for those components,
 * and automatically refreshing the context.
 * @param basePackages the packages to scan for component classes
 */
public AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(String... basePackages) {
    this();
    scan(basePackages);
    refresh();  <--------------
}
```

As you can see the `refresh` method is executed **but** remember that this constructor execution happens **before** of the `setActiveProfiles` execution.

Therefore

**Question**

- Why the *active profiles* declared *programmatically* are working if the `refresh` method was not executed?

Even more, like a simple plus, if is executed as:

```
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx =
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.manuel.jordan.config");
    ctx.getEnvironment().setDefaultProfiles("default", "dev");
    ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("jdbc", "mysql");
    ctx.refresh(); <---
```

Arises

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory (GenericApplicationContext.java:293)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory (AbstractApplicationContext.java:672)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:554)
    at com.manuel.jordan.main.Main.main (Main.java:28)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: "But it works, through the following code it was confirmed" - that code actually confirms nothing: you are just modifying internal state of `AbstractEnvironment` and checking it's state has been changed, that doesn't prove profiles have been actually applied.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov agree, one thing is see the profile(s) declared and other is confirm if they were really applied or not. Consider to write and expand your answer to mark it as valid. Thanks

Comment: alternatives: 1. `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();` 2. `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(new DefaultListableBeanFactory());` ...`ctx.scan("com.example");ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("jdbc", "mysql"); ctx.refresh();//!`