# When is mandatory define the profiles through Environment over System.setProperty and viceversa?

Tags: spring, profile

For Spring about Profiles, the following is legal

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.manuel.jordan.config");
ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("jdbc", "mysql");
...
```

But the following approach is valid too.

```
//B1
System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "jdbc", "mysql");
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.manuel.jordan.config");
...
```

Both approaches are applied in peace and the app works as expected ... but

**Question**

- When is mandatory define the profiles through `Environment` over `System.setProperty` and viceversa?

**Extra Question**

- Why was created the approach to define a profile (*default* or *active*) through `Environment` if can be accomplished through `System.setProperty` too? Being the later plain Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.manuel.jordan.config");
ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("jdbc", "mysql");
...
```

Here you have to watch out! Your active profiles are `jdbc` and `mysql` as expected. But **NO** beans were created based on those profiles!

In the second approach with `System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "jdbc, mysql");` (before creating the `ApplicationContext`) beans will be created based on those profiles!

Demo

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "jdbc")
    @Profile("jdbc")
    public MyProfileClass jdbc(){
        return new MyProfileClass("jdbc");
    }

    @Bean(name = "mysql")
    @Profile("mysql")
    public MyProfileClass mysql(){
        return new MyProfileClass("mysql");
    }

    @Bean(name = "notJdbc")
    @Profile("!jdbc")
    public MyProfileClass notJdbc(){
        return new MyProfileClass("not jdbc");
    }

    @Bean(name = "notMysql")
    @Profile("!mysql")
    public MyProfileClass notMysql(){
        return new MyProfileClass("not mysql");
    }
}

public class MyProfileClass {

    private final String name;

    public MyProfileClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}


public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "jdbc,mysql");
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.manuel.jordan.config");
        ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("jdbc", "mysql"); // to late beans based on profile already created

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ctx.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()));

        for (String beanName:ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(ctx.getBean(beanName));
        }
    }
}
```

There are more options to activate different profiles: [Baeldung :: Spring Profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

---

UPDATE

When you want to set the active profiles programmatically use, you need to refresh the context.

like:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("jdbc", "mysql");
ctx.scan("com.manuel.jordan.config");
ctx.refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I am doing my experiment by my side for confirmations and other things - just being curious if `ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("jdbc", "mysql");` does **not** work, Therefore What is its purpose?

Comment: `ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("jdbc", "mysql")` only works if you refresh the context; @see update

Comment: About the `refresh` method - pls, read carefully the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75442297/spring-framework-why-the-active-profiles-declared-programmatically-are-working - specially starting from _Even more, like a simple plus, if is executed as:_ - it seems the approach to create the App is tricky ... in your case you use the non-arguments constructor and my case yes (in the other post) now is clear for me when use the `register` and `scan` methods and later the `refresh` method